# ~/.ssh/config is getting wiped on OS X

Tags: bash, ssh

Hello wonderful Super Users!

I have the weirdest issue where my `~/.ssh/config` file is getting wiped at a semi-regular interval. I haven't narrowed down the timing of it, but it seems to happen sometime during the night. The file still exists, but the contents have been removed. I use `zsh` and `oh-my-zsh`. I was talking to a co-worker who has the same issue and is using `bash`, so it's neither of those two things. I'm not even sure how I would debug this!

Comment: I'd ask your IT department, if ssh is allowed, it's weird they'd be wiping it out, but it's possibly something they're doing.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ls -l` to check the modification time on `~/.ssh/config`, and then you could look for something in `/etc/crontab`, `/etc/cron.hourly/` (and daily/etc), or `/etc/cron.d/` to see if there is a cron job that's responsible. At the very least, you can get an idea of whether it always happens at the same exact time. While you're using `ls -l`, check to make sure only the owner has write permissions on the file.

If you have access to the log files on the system, you could look for entries in `/var/log/auth.log`, etc. from around the time that the file was modified; maybe someone is accessing your accounts. Or, if you don't have access to the logs, ask the sysadmin. It seems like something they should be interested in.

Another thing you could try is looking for the filename in your ~/.bash_history:

```
grep "~/.ssh/config" ~/.bash_history
```